# Как можно парсить данные с Python?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Как достать данные о цене акции тут: https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/stocks/RDS.A/
Пытался сделать так, но выходит None:

```
link_ticker = "https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/stocks/RDS.A/"
    data_base = requests.get(link_ticker).text
    data = BeautifulSoup(data_base, "html.parser")
    price = data.find('text', {'class': 'Tooltip__tooltipText_1PLnU'})
    print(price)
```

Comment: Не думаю что bs4 может Вам в данной ситуации. Там весь контент скриптами прогружается. Попробуйте selenium использовать

Comment: Можете подсказать как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# небольшой напилинг selenium Firefox 
# (Можно обойтись без него но мне лень переписывать WebDriverWait тем более что он там проверен и работает как надо)

from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement import FirefoxWebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class FirefoxBrowser(Firefox):
    def __init__(self,
                 silent_mode: bool = False,
                 driver: str = 'geckodriver',
                 close_timeout: int = 0,
                 max_window: bool = True,
                 no_images: bool = True):

        """
        Надстройка к драйверу selenium Firefox. С персональной кастомизацией

        :param silent_mode: логическое, по умолчанию False отвечает за отображение окна браузера.;

        :param driver: указывает расположение файла `geckodriver`. Если файл находится не в директории проекта  (не забываем скачать бинарник (exe'шник для Windows) и закинуть его в папку со скриптом либо в любую из PATH)
        необходимо указать полный путь к файлу, или добавить путь к файлу в переменную PATH;

        :param close_timeout: время задержки до закрытия окна браузера после завершения работы. По умолчании 0 сек.;  # чето не зашло у меня с этим параметром поэтому не используется

        :param max_window: параметр отвечающий за развертывание окна браузера до максимального размера при запуске
        :param no_images: блокировка изображений на сайтах.
        """

        self.__close_timeout = close_timeout

        if silent_mode:
            max_window = False

        opt = FirefoxOptions()
        opt.headless = silent_mode

        profile = FirefoxProfile()

        if no_images:
            profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)

        super().__init__(options=opt,
                         executable_path=driver,
                         firefox_profile=profile)
        if max_window:
            self.maximize_window()

    def scroll_to_element(self, element: FirefoxWebElement):
        self.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

    def wait_for_element(self, by: By, ident: str, timeout: int = 5):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(
                expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                    (by, ident)
                )
            )
            return self.find_element(by, ident)
        except TimeoutException:
            return None

    @property
    def action(self):
        return ActionChains(self)
```

Теперь собственно ответ на вопрос:

```py
site = FirefoxBrowser()
# Если смущают "спецэффекты" в виде открывающегося окна Firefox
# то можно site = FirefoxBrowser(silent_mode=True)

site.get('https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/stocks/RDS.A/')
needed = site.wait_for_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Tooltip__tooltipText_1PLnU')
if needed:
    print(needed.text)
# 33,1
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Stepan/Desktop/hhh.py", line 79, in <module>
    site = FirefoxBrowser()
  File "C:/Users/Stepan/Desktop/hhh.py", line 56, in __init__
    service_log_path=files.temp_dir / 'geckodriver.log')
NameError: name 'files' is not defined

Comment: Что тут не то сделал?

Comment: @Валера ща сек, это мой косяк, выдергивал из рабочего кода, не все подчистил

Comment: @Валера, Сейчас перекопируйте код и попробуйте

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rzu1wDGZ

Comment: Такая ошибка...

Comment: @Валера `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases подберите под свою систему драйвер, скачайте и закинте в папку со скриптом екзешник (ну или бинарник если у вас линукс)

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.

Comment: И да. Если у Вас не стоит Firefox (браузер) то его тоже не плохо бы поставить

Comment: @Валера, лучшее спасибо - принятый ответ ))))

Comment: А если я захочу этот скрипт на сервак загрузить, то нужно будет там установить Firefox?

Comment: @Валера. Да `sudo apt install firefox` и бинарник в `/usr/bin` закинуть не забудьте

Comment: Как это будет там вообще работать?

Comment: А понял спасибо большое.

Comment: @Валера, нормально будет работать. silent_mode=True. У мну на ubuntu-server половина парсеров на нем крутятся

Comment: А где лучше вообще инфу про парсеры брать?

Comment: @Валера, почитайте документацию по bs4 (aka. BeautifulSoup), Selenium, Scrapy. Ну и естественно по HTML для общего понимания DOM html документа

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в инспектор браузера на вкладке Network откуда сайт берет данные.

Этот сайт отдает данные по АПИ без авторизации:

отправляете POST с json на `https://api.tinkoff.ru/trading/symbols/candles?sessionId=DjsxrsV2k8Rphjmmeity5Z1TmHyDF2VO.ds-prod-api27` где sessionId похоже не обязательна

```
{"from":"2020-07-05T12:27:46+03:00","to":"2020-07-19T12:27:46+03:00","resolution":60,"ticker":"RDS.A"}
```

получаете свечки в json

```
{"payload":{
 "candles": 
 [{"o":33.94,"c":33.37,"h":33.94,"l":33.1,"v":1370,"date":1594018800},
 ....,
 {"o":33.1,"c":33.1,"h":33.1,"l":33.1,"v":4,"date":1595023200}]
},
"trackingId":"1446f81bd84cfc2e",
"time":"2020-07-19T12:29:31.739+03:00",
"status":"Ok"}
```

o,c - открытие, закрытие
h,l - верхниее, нижнее

```py
import requests

payloads = {

        "from": "2020-07-05T12:27:46+03:00",
        "to": "2020-07-19T12:27:46+03:00",
        "resolution": 60,
        "ticker": "RDS.A"
}

response = requests.post('https://api.tinkoff.ru/trading/symbols/candles', json=payloads)
print(response.json())
# {'payload': {'candles': [{'o': 33.94, 'c': 33.37, 'h': 33.94, 'l': 33.1, 'v': 1370, 'date': 1594018800}, ...вырезанно... , {'o': 33.1, 'c': 33.1, 'h': 33.1, 'l': 33.1, 'v': 4, 'date': 1595023200}]}, 'trackingId': '94e8ec7237cc65fc', 'time': '2020-07-19T12:49:19.202+03:00', 'status': 'Ok'}
```

Работает также и с GET.

Comment: Дооформите? Или мне добить ответ со ссылкой на Вас?

Comment: можете поправить мой ответ?

Comment: @Namerek - c гет тоже работает

Comment: Да, только нужно payloads передавать не в `json` а в `params`

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает через bs4 просто парсить всю страницу по ссылке,а там уже поиском по строке найти нужный параметр?
https://api-invest.tinkoff.ru/smartfeed-public/v1/feed/api/brands/Royal%20Dutch%20Shell%20PLC/news?sessionId=sv4DAPcPfLkb4QQXD1xq37gi1d8v98Sh.ds-prod-api48&limit=10
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это самый простой вариант без Post запросов...

Comment: Можно поменять https://api-invest.tinkoff.ru/smartfeed-public/v1/feed/api/brands/Royal%20Dutch%20Shell%20PLC/news?sessionId=sv4DAPcPfLkb4QQXD1xq37gi1d8v98Sh.ds-prod-api48&limit=1 ,это еще облегчит процесс

Comment: Не уверен, что ваш вариант проще чем post с нормальным структурированным ответом в json

Comment: А зачем парсить, если получили готовые данные?

Comment: @Namerek новичку точно будет проще понять)Учитывая ,что в его коде надо поменять лишь link_ticker и маркер поиска.При желании можно и издеваться над веб-соккетом)

Answer (score 0):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

response = session.get('https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/stocks/RDS.A/')
response.html.render()
get_price = response.html.xpath('//*[@class="Tooltip__tooltipText_1PLnU"]//text()')
print(get_price)
```